# How to grep/print value of a key in json that is stored in a variable?

Tags: shell-script, awk, grep, json

I have a variable with nested json,

```
a={"content":[{"JOB_STATUS_ID":283739,"PROGRAM_ID":57,"STATUS":"Completed","**DATA_DATE**":"2017-03-09 00:00:00","**START_TIME**":"2017-03-10 00:46:13","END_TIME":"2017-03-10 00:56:40","TOTAL_ROWS":null,"UPDATED_ROWS":null,"DELETED_ROWS":null,"INSERTED_ROWS":null,"REF1":"NULL","REF2":"NULL","AUD_CREATE_DT":"2017-03-10 00:46:13","AUD_CREATE_USER":"JOB_CONTROL","AUD_MODIFY_DT":"2017-03-10 00:56:40","AUD_MODIFY_USER":"JOB_CONTROL"},

{"JOB_STATUS_ID":109711,"PROGRAM_ID":57,"STATUS":"Completed","DATA_DATE":"2017-01-11 00:00:00","START_TIME":"2017-01-12 16:55:14","END_TIME":"2017-01-12 18:54:51","TOTAL_ROWS":null,"UPDATED_ROWS":null,"DELETED_ROWS":null,"INSERTED_ROWS":null,"REF1":"NULL","REF2":"NULL","AUD_CREATE_DT":"2017-01-12 16:55:14","AUD_CREATE_USER":"JOB_CONTROL","AUD_MODIFY_DT":"2017-01-12}
```

Looking for a way to grep the DATA_DATE and START_TIME of the first json in the nested json (like the one highlighted) in variable a.

Any help?

Okay to use awk,sed or shell scripting.

Comment: format your description

Comment: Your JSON example seems to be partial and broken.

Answer (score 2):

Use [jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq):

```
$ echo $a | jq '.[][0]["**DATA_DATE**"]'
"2017-03-09 00:00:00"
```

As jq may not be available to all distros and you may not want to compile it yourself you may take advantage of many other scripting languages that have JSON support in their basic libraries.

Perl:

```
$ perl -e "use JSON::Parse 'parse_json'; my \$a = parse_json ('$(echo $a)'); print \$a->{'content'}[0]{'**DATA_DATE**'}"
2017-03-09 00:00:00
```

Python:

```
$ python -c "import json; a=json.loads('$(echo $a)'); print(a['content'][0]['**DATA_DATE**'])"
2017-03-09 00:00:00
```

Ruby:

```
$ ruby -e "require 'json'; puts JSON.parse('$a')['content'][0]['**DATA_DATE**'];"
2017-03-09 00:00:00
```

Of course you may (ab)use standard *nix (GNU) tools to get your values from this specific JSON example but that's really not convenient. You may take first line Once the JSON structure changes your code will behave unpredictably.

Comment: You appear to be using `$a` unquoted throughout.  Also note that `echo` may modify the data that it's outputting under some circumstances (e.g. if it contains backslash escapes like `\n` and `\t`, which is sometimes found in JSON documents).

Answer (score 1):

For JSON, you use a tool that understand JSON, e.g. [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), and not awk/sed:

```
$ echo "$a" | jq '.content[0].DATA_DATE'
"2017-03-09 00:00:00"
```

Similarly for `START_TIME`. For most distros, *jq* is available as a package.

Answer (score 0):

I am a fan of using Perl lookarounds for this kind of thing

> echo $a | grep -oP '(?<=DATE**:).*?(?=,)'

and

> echo $a | grep -oP '(?<=START_TIME**:).*?(?=,)'

Comment: am getting this output

echo $a | grep -oP '(?<=START_TIME**:).*?(?=,)'
grep: nothing to repeat

Comment: This does not seem to work at all.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, it is **far better** to use a language (like perl or python or ruby) which have libraries for parsing json, or a special-purpose tool that does so like `jq`...but if you really want or need to process json data with common tools like `awk` or `sed`, then you first have to convert it into a line-oriented format.

Why?  Because you can not reliably parse json with just regular expressions, and even if you think you've succeeded what you have will be incredibly fragile and prone to breaking with even trivial changes to the expected input.

`jsonpipe` (written in python) is one such tool that can perform the conversion to line-oriented format.  e.g. after fixing the broken json in your example, it produces the following output:

```
$ jsonpipe < /tmp/nick.json 
/   {}
/content    []
/content/0  {}
/content/0/JOB_STATUS_ID    283739
/content/0/PROGRAM_ID   57
/content/0/STATUS   "Completed"
/content/0/**DATA_DATE**    "2017-03-09 00:00:00"
/content/0/**START_TIME**   "2017-03-10 00:46:13"
/content/0/END_TIME "2017-03-10 00:56:40"
/content/0/TOTAL_ROWS   null
/content/0/UPDATED_ROWS null
/content/0/DELETED_ROWS null
/content/0/INSERTED_ROWS    null
/content/0/REF1 "NULL"
/content/0/REF2 "NULL"
/content/0/AUD_CREATE_DT    "2017-03-10 00:46:13"
/content/0/AUD_CREATE_USER  "JOB_CONTROL"
/content/0/AUD_MODIFY_DT    "2017-03-10 00:56:40"
/content/0/AUD_MODIFY_USER  "JOB_CONTROL"
/content/1  {}
/content/1/JOB_STATUS_ID    109711
/content/1/PROGRAM_ID   57
/content/1/STATUS   "Completed"
/content/1/DATA_DATE    "2017-01-11 00:00:00"
/content/1/START_TIME   "2017-01-12 16:55:14"
/content/1/END_TIME "2017-01-12 18:54:51"
/content/1/TOTAL_ROWS   null
/content/1/UPDATED_ROWS null
/content/1/DELETED_ROWS null
/content/1/INSERTED_ROWS    null
/content/1/REF1 "NULL"
/content/1/REF2 "NULL"
/content/1/AUD_CREATE_DT    "2017-01-12 16:55:14"
/content/1/AUD_CREATE_USER  "JOB_CONTROL"
/content/1/AUD_MODIFY_DT    "2017-01-12"
```

That allows you to process it with the standard text processing utilities.  For example:

```
$ jsonpipe < /tmp/nick.json  | \
  sed -ne 's:^/content/0/\*\*DATA_DATE\*\*[[:space:]]\+::p'
"2017-03-09 00:00:00"

$ jsonpipe < /tmp/nick.json  | \
  awk -F'"' '/^\/content\/0\// && /DATA_DATE/ {print $2}'
2017-03-09 00:00:00
```

or even something as crude as this:

```
$ jsonpipe < /tmp/nick.json  | grep '/0/.*DATA_DATE'
/content/0/**DATA_DATE**    "2017-03-09 00:00:00"
```

---

On debian and derivative systems, it is packaged as `python-jsonpipe`, and probably has a similar package name on other distros.  Or it can be found at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonpipe

NOTE: it comes with a corresponding `jsonunpipe` tool which you can use to convert that line-oriented format back into json - e.g. after modifying it with `sed` or `awk` or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `**` characters in the JSON keys are just markup, and not actually part of your data, and that you want to read the two values into two separate shell variables, `data_date` and `start_time`, you may make `jq` produce the shell code for the assignments and then evaluate that in the shell:

```bsh
a='{ the JSON document }'

eval "$(
    printf '%s\n' "$a" |
    jq -r '.content[0] |
        @sh "data_date=\(.DATA_DATE)",
        @sh "start_time=\(.START_TIME)"'
)" 

printf 'data date  = "%s"\n' "$data_date"
printf 'start time = "%s"\n' "$start_time"
```

Given the data in the question (and that it is corrected first), the `jq` call here generates the shell code

```bsh
data_date='2017-03-09 00:00:00'
start_time='2017-03-10 00:46:13'
```

which is then evaluated using `eval` in the script.